# Univariate adaptive kernel density estimation in R

Tags: r, kernel-density

Is there an R function which can calculate an adaptive kernel density function for univariate observations. What about akj (package `quantreg`)? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please find the answer below and consider accepting it if it suits you, otherwise I would be pleased to know why it does not answer to your question!

Comment: Colonel Beauvel, It seems that your kernel density estimator is not a variable one. I do not see where you are varying the smoothing parameter (h), or any distance measure. Another problem: when I integrate the data, the CDF is greater than 1 (I ran your code with a univariate normal and compare it with rnorm).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about the package but it is quite simple to implement it yourself (this will also make your understand exactly what you are doing), for example lets take these values in the plan:

```
g = 5
n = 100
set.seed(g)
df = data.frame(x = unlist(lapply(1:g, function(i) rnorm(n/g, runif(1)*i))),
                y= unlist(lapply(1:g, function(i) rnorm(n/g, runif(1)*i))))

plot(df)
```

[image]

Let's assume you want to estimate the density at three point `x1 = c(6,-1)`, `x2 = c(0.3, 2)`, `x3=c(3, -0.5)` on this distribution. The density should be weak on x1, high on x2 and the density on x3 should be between these two low and high densities:

```
points(6,-1, col='red', pch=19)
points(0.3,2, col='blue', pch=19)
points(3,-0.5, col='green', pch=19)
```

[image]

According to the definition of an adaptative kernel density function:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_kernel_density_estimation

```
library(functional)

gaussianKernel = function(u, h) exp(-sum(u^2)/(2*h^2))

densityFunction = function(x, df, ker, h)
{
    difference = t(t(df) - x)
    W = sum(apply(difference, 1, ker, h=h))
    W/(nrow(df)*(h^(length(df))))
}

myDensityFunction = Curry(densityFunction, df=df, ker=gaussianKernel , h=2)
```

And we have the confirmation of the intuitive result: `0 <= P(x1) < P(x3) < P(x2) <=1`

```
#> myDensityFunction(x1)
#[1] 0.02140895
#> myDensityFunction(x2)
#[1] 0.1146402
#> myDensityFunction(x3)
#[1] 0.09341908
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Is this method similar to the adaptive kernel a la silverman? I saw it in "Kernel methods for estimating the utilization distribution in home-range studies" (B.J. Worton)

Comment: Colonel Beauvel, It seems that your kernel density estimator is not a variable one. I do not see where you are varying the smoothing parameter (h), or any distance measure. Another problem: when I integrate the data, the CDF is greater than 1 (I ran your code with a univariate normal and compare it with rnorm).